# How does a Raspberry Pi 3 react with low voltage as batteries die?

Tags: power, power-supply, battery, shutdown

How does the Raspberry pi react as voltage drops from batteries die? Does it eventually automatically halt or do I need to worry about unpredictable side effects from running the batteries dead?

Comment: You could corrupt the SD card by undervolting the Pi.

Comment: So there is detecting this by the Pi and shutting down before the logic potentially fails from low voltage?

Comment: @David not without external hardware

Comment: This is an unanswerable question. The result is undefined. Rather focus on detecting an issue and deciding on a course of action to avoid any consequences.

Comment: This seem relevant https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373  . Sounds like there is internal software that you could leverage to read this as root if its showing up in Raspian. Also it could be used to trigger shutoff I would hope?